# Is it possible to compare a value against an array of values in Kusto?

Tags: arrays, azure-data-explorer, kql

Is it possible to compare a value against an array of values in Kusto?

I can do the check like this:

```
letters
| where letter == "A" or letter == "B" or letter == "C"
```

But since I have to add and remove the characters (and sometimes there are up to 10 characters) so often it gets tiresome to type out the whole `or letter == "{some letter}"` every time.

Is there a construct like the following in Kusto:

```
letters
| where ["A", "B", "C"] contains letter
```

?

A mere googling did not give any results. I guess it is because I do not know what the construct is called, so my Google searches miss the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic) data type

```
let letters = datatable(letter:string)["C", "O", "B", "R", "A", "-", "K", "A", "I"];
letters
| where letter in (dynamic(["A", "B", "C"]))
```

| letter |
| --- |
| C |
| B |
| A |
| A |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVHISS0pSS0qVrBVSEksAcKknFQNiJhVcUlRZl66ZrSSs5KOgpI/iHACEUEgwhFE6IIIbzjXUynWmgtqIFeNQnlGalEq1AKFzDwFjZTKvMTczGSNaIhysGHOSrGamgBBmtXciQAAAA==)